# Keep track of iteration with parametrized Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This code:

```
Kid[] kids = Kid.getSimpleArray();
String names = Stream.of(kids)
                .filter(Kid::hasToy)
                .map(Kid::getSurname)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
out.println(names);
```

gives me this result:

*Stępień, Inglot, Czubówna, Lepiej, Łagowska*

And I'm thinking of a solution to make it like this:

*1.Stępień, 2.Inglot, 3.Czubówna, 4.Lepiej, 5.Łagowska*

P.S I couldn't think of a better question to get answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Basically: streams are not intended to do this, and if you've got a `filter` in there you're almost completely out of luck.  No, seriously: streams can't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Note that this is really ugly and not an advice I should give here but here it is.***

You may use a temporary collection that will serve us as a counter. The advantage is that we can block the reference as final but still add elements to it.

We add whatever to it each time a `Kid` passes the filter and get the size for the integer in your String.

```
final List tmp = new ArrayList();
Kid[] kids = Kid.getSimpleArray();
String names = Stream.of(kids)
                .filter(Kid::hasToy)
                .peek(x -> tmp.add(1))
                .map(x -> tmp.size() + "." + x.getSurname())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
out.println(names);
```

---

### EDIT

Here are two other solutions provided by @Sam and @Tunaki

---

### @Sam

```
final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
Kid[] kids = Kid.getSimpleArray();
String names = Stream.of(kids)
                .filter(Kid::hasToy)
                .map(x -> ai.incrementAndGet() + "." + x.getSurname())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
out.println(names);
```

---

### @Tunaki

```
Kid[] kids = Kid.getSimpleArray();
Kid[] filteredKids = Arrays.stream(kids).filter(Kid::hasToy).toArray(Kid[]::new);
String names = IntStream.range(0, filteredKids.length)
                        .mapToObj(i -> i + "." + filteredKids[i].getSurname())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ");
out.println(names);
```

Comment: indeed it is ugly ;) I was thinking there is a proper way to do this. If no one will provide better answer soon I will accept yours.

Comment: @Tomek Well as said above, Streams are not meant to behave like this. But there's always a (sometimes ugly) trick.

Comment: Nice idea. You could improve it even more by using an `AtomicInteger` (or some other mutable counter) instead of a list. With the `incrementAndGet` method you wouldn't even need to use the extra `peek`.

Comment: The only solution I see without such hacks is to do it in 2 passes. First pass keeps the kids having toys, and the second pass uses an `IntStream` over the indices of the filtered array...

Comment: this is nice! I even thought about second solution a minute ago.

Comment: Is this an attempt to be as ugly as possible? Besides the abuse of `peek`, the dependency to mutable state, the idea of abusing an `ArrayList` with increasing memory allocation as a counter raises it up to eleven. That’s not even related to Java 8, you are guaranteed to get a WTF?! even when seeing it in Java 2 code…

Comment: @Tomek: this is far away from being nice. The first and second solution are rather examples of what you should *never* do.

Answer (score 3):

Using third-party free library [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) (written by me) which enhances standard Stream API you can [zip](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#zipWith-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) the stream with numbers:

```
String result = StreamEx.of("abc", "def", "aaa", "foo", "a12", "a34", "bar", "aaa")
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("a"))
    .zipWith(IntStreamEx.ints().boxed(), (str, num) -> (num+1)+". "+str)
    .joining(", ");
// 1. abc, 2. aaa, 3. a12, 4. a34, 5. aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

Streams only operate on one item at once. Each computation knows only about the element it is operating on. So trying to add in some knowledge of the item's position in the ordering is always going to be a hack.

Collecting into a `List` instead of a String would allow you to do a final computation that operates on the list of all the items, rather than on single items in isolation. Here's a method that takes the `List` and formats it as a comma-separated `String` of numbered items:

```
static String enumerateAndJoin(List<String> l, String separator) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    ListIterator<String> it = l.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(it.nextIndex() + 1).append(".").append(it.next());
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(separator);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You could of course then do:

```
 List<String> surnames = Stream.of(kids)
            .filter(Kid::hasToy)
            .map(Kid::getSurname)
            .collect(toList());

 String output = enumerateAndJoin(surnames, ", ");
```

But if you're using this in several places, it might be convenient to define a new collector.

```
Collector<String, ?, String> myCollector = collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> enumerateAndJoin(list, ", "));

String output = Stream.of(kids)
            .filter(Kid::hasToy)
            .map(Kid::getSurname)
            .collect(myCollector);
```

However, all this really serves to do is obscure the code and waste cycles. Ultimately we're now doing two passes over the items. And the 'hack' solutions that just do one pass work by treating the stream as if it is an iterator, counting how many items have been encountered. That approach will only work for very straightforward ordered streams, and isn't at all what streams are intended for.

The stream is certainly appealing for its fluent `filter` and `map` methods. But if you can bear a bit more verbosity, why not just iterate over `kids` using a real iterator in the first place?

```
int i = 0;
Iterator<Kid> it = new ArrayIterator<>(kids);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Kid kid = it.next();
    if (!kid.hasToy()) continue;
    sb.append(++i).append(".").append(kid.getSurname());
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

For a `hybrid` approach that saves a line or two and is arguably clearer, I like  Guava's `FluentIterable`:

```
int i = 0;
Iterator<Kid> kidsWithToys = FluentIterable.of(kids).filter(Kid::hasToy).iterator();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (kidsWithToys.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(++i).append(".").append(kidsWithToys.next().getSurname());
    if (kidsWithToys.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

For some problems, streams are not the answer, and I think this is one of them.

Comment: `"why not just iterate over kids using a real iterator in the first place?"` because I wanted to make use of laziness of streams with filter method...

Comment: You say you want to make use of laziness. I take it that means you aren't using the `joining(", ")` collector in your real world application, then? I would still use an iterator. You could use Guava to construct the filtered iterator, and then further decorate it to emit numbered items. That way the filtering is still lazy. I can edit my answer if it's not clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, after all the filtering is done, Strings are collected and joined. Since you want to end up with String values, we can create a version of `toString()` (forgetting for the moment that your Stream already contains Strings) that prepends the count, like this:

```
public static<T> Function<T, String> getCountedToStringFunc(){
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return t -> i.incrementAndGet() + ". " + t.toString();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
myStream
.filter(...)
.map(getCountedToStringFunc())
.collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Or, noting that having to remember to apply the counter as late as possible in the pipeline creates a maintainability risk if you should want to modify the pipeline in the future, you could take it out of the pipeline altogether and make it part of the terminating function:

```
myStream
.filter(...)
.collect(Collectors.mapping(getCountedToStringFunc(),joining(","))));
```

The nice thing about the latter approach is you could use it to create separate counters for partitioned or grouped data.